# store outputs during recursion

Tags: algorithm, matlab, recursion, store

I'm trying to write a code that store all of the outputs from a recursion under a certain condition.

My MATLAB code looks like this:

```
function answer= rec_solve(M, remainingValue, previousLevel, solutionSoFar)
if (M == 1)
    answer= [solutionSoFar remainingValue];
    % store only the outputs that reach here
else
for i=previousLevel:remainingValue/M
    s= [solutionSoFar i];
    rec_solve(M-1, remainingValue-i, i, s);
    end
end
end
```

I tried to store in a matrix only the outputs that reach the condition (M==1) but without success.
I think that it should be wraped in other function, but i don't have a clue how to wrap it in the right way.
It's like I want to store exaclly the printing results if the ';' is taken down inside the condition (line 3).

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: well, answer is the output of the function so I dont see why you dont get it out as result ? do you loop over the function or where exactly is the problem storing it ?

Comment: The things is that I want to store only the answers from the 'If' statemant. There are multiple times through the recursion that reach there, how can I do such thing? The final answer is only 1 out of N answers I need.

Comment: Can you give us a sample input and the desired output for this function?

Comment: input: rec_solve(3,3,0,0). output: [0 0 0 3; 0 0 1 2; 0 1 1 1]. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work as you wish:

```
function answer= rec_solve(M, remainingValue, previousLevel, solutionSoFar)

 k=0;
    if (M == 1)
        k=k+1;
        answer(k,:)= [solutionSoFar remainingValue];
        % store only the outputs that reach here
    else
      for i=previousLevel:remainingValue/M
        s= [solutionSoFar i];
        rec_solve(M-1, remainingValue-i, i, s);
        end
      end
    end
```

but not knowing the size of `answer` maybe you want to modify `(k,:)` in something else. 
Also, if `answer` changes size you want to define `answer` before the loop:

```
function answer= rec_solve(M, remainingValue, previousLevel, solutionSoFar)

answer=zeros(1,N);
k=0;

if (M == 1)
    k=k+1;
    answer(k,1:numel([solutionSoFar remainingValue])= [solutionSoFar remainingValue];
    % store only the outputs that reach here
else
  for i=previousLevel:remainingValue/M
    s= [solutionSoFar i];
    rec_solve(M-1, remainingValue-i, i, s);
    end
  end
end
```

where `N` is greater than the maximum length that `[solutionSoFar remainingValue]` can have.

Maybe not the most elegant solution.. but it should work.

Comment: note that my answer will create a matrix in which the lines will be `[solutionSoFar remainingValue]`. I am not sure that this is what you want. I do not know your code. In principle my answer suggests to store what you want to store in successive lines of a matrix